# Welcome page of subsite - Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How to extract url of Welcome page of subsite?

I mean, I have sth like this

```
-SiteRoot
--Pages
----Default.aspx         <---------HERE I AM
--Subsites
----SiteOne
------Pages
--------Home.aspx        <---------I NEED THIS
----SiteTwo
------Pages
--------Home2.aspx       <---------I NEED THIS
```

And I would like to get information about URL of landing pages of subsites

Could you help me?

I have wrote sth like this:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
foreach (SPWeb w in web.Webs)
            {
                MenuItem item = new MenuItem();

                item.Url = w.RootFolder.WelcomePage;
                item.Title = w.Title;

                MenuItems.Add(item);
            }
```

But it takes welcome page of my Root folder, so Default.aspx

Comment: That looks correct - are you sure the pages you're trying to query for are indeed set as the Homepage of the subsites in question? If that code is still returning "default.aspx", that would suggest the Homepage of those subsites has not been correctly changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I done that:

```
        foreach (SPWeb w in web.Webs)
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();

            System.Uri uri = new Uri(w.Url);
            item.Url = uri.LocalPath +"/"+ w.GetFolder(w.Url).WelcomePage;
            item.Title = w.Title;

            MenuItems.Add(item);
        }
```